# Function which applies a groupby

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have numerous dataframes I want to apply a function to.

My dataframes look like this:

```
Year  ID   Pressure
1984  1    0.2
1985  2    0.5
1986  3    0.7
```

I am trying:

```
def f(x):
   return x.groupby(['ID']).Pressure.mean().to_frame().reset_index()

#apply the function to dataframes
df.apply(f)
df2.apply(f)
```

but this returns:

```
 KeyError: ('ID', u'occurred at index Year')
```

without a function I can do what I want like this:

```
df=df.groupby(['ID']).Pressure.mean().to_frame().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply is used when you want to `apply` a `function` to every values of a dataframe. since you just want to apply something to the entire df you should just do:

```
f(df)
f(df2)
```